# Why is my SQL stored procedure not updating a specific value in the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure containing the following code (simplified and genericised):

```sql
UPDATE t
SET t.intFoo = @foo,
    t.intBar = @bar,
    t.intBaz = tst.intBaz
FROM dbo.myTable t,
     dbo.myOtherTable tst
WHERE (t.id = @myId)
AND (tst.alias = 'Alias')
```

`@foo` is generated earlier on in the stored procedure, while `@bar` is passed in as an `int` parameter. `intBar` is known to be null on every row in the table.

After the stored procedure is called, when I check the updated row in the database, I see that `intFoo` and `intBaz` have been set correctly, but `intBar` is still set to null. This happens even if I explicitly hardcode a value for `intBar` to be set to:

```sql
UPDATE t
SET t.intFoo = 12345, --this gets stored in the targeted row
    t.intBar = 54321, --this does not; it remains null
    ...
```

`intBar` is a completely ordinary column, with no constraints or anything that would block it from being set:

```sql
...
[intBar] [int] NULL
```

I have run the stored procedure in isolation, and confirmed that a) `@bar` is being passed in correctly and is not null, and b) the value of `intBar` is not being overwritten by another stored procedure. I've tried running just the `UPDATE` statement in isolation, and again, `intBar` is not updated while every other value is.

**What's going on here?** Why is my stored procedure updating *some* of the values I'm asking it to, but not *all* of them?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: Post the stored procedure - not just a fragment.

Comment: If you run the update statement outside of the stored proc, does it do what you expect?

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan No. If I run it by itself, it does the exact same thing, and updates every column except `intBar`.

Comment: I assume there's no triggers on the table?

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan I've checked, and yes, there are no triggers.

Comment: Reading the previous comment, may I conclude this has nothing to do with the stored procedure?   Please provide a [mre] (without the stored procedure stuff), and the DDL of that table.

Comment: In that case, as @Luuk says, it'll probably be some obscure thing that we need more context in order to find. An explicit `JOIN` syntax would be better but wouldn't be the root cause of your issue. If possible, please provide your DDL for the relevant tables and the full update query

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about doing that. This is production code (well, it will be if I can fix the problem, and obviously I've redacted the column and variable names). The full table and proc are quite large, I'd have to redact the names of all the columns, and 90% of them aren't relevant to the proc or to the issue I'm experiencing.

Comment: `The full table and proc are quite large` We can only find problems in code that we can see, try to reduce the proc as much as you can so you have a small reproducable example. Very often you come across the error while doing so

Comment: @GuidoG is correct - the amount of times I've had that "Oh" moment while halfway through writing the stackoverflow question is painful

Comment: Pretty sure it will be because there is no relationship between myTable and myOtherTable.  As already suggested use an explicit join clause :
````
FROM
      myTable AS t
JOIN
     myOtherTable AS tst ON tst.t_linked_ID = T.ID
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After closer inspection, it turns out there *was* a trigger on the table that was controlling the updates. (I couldn't find it initially because this is extremely messy legacy code and nothing is where you expect it to be.) `intBar` was only recently added to the table, and must not have been added to the trigger at that time, therefore it wasn't being included in the update.

I updated the trigger to include `intBar` and now it works perfectly.